# asyncio only running first gpiozero coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gpio, gpiozero

I'm trying to make `gpiozero` play nicely with `asyncio` in my RPi 4 but ran into an issue that I can't solve. Essentially I'm trying to get the turn signal (clock wise, counter clock wise) af a rotary enoder as well es detect if the button of the RE has been pressed.
I'm using asyncio to gather coroutines and run them simultaneously (the other corountines so far working as expected). But when I try to run the button detection and rotary detection, only the first one in the list ever gets started.

Here's the excerpt of the code that's not working for me:

```
import asyncio
from gpiozero import RotaryEncoder, Button

button = Button(7)
encoder = RotaryEncoder(a=10, b=9, wrap=False, max_steps=0)

async def rotary_detection():
  print("rotary_detection started")
  last_rotary_value = 0
  try:
    while True:
      current_rotary_value = encoder.steps
      if last_rotary_value != current_rotary_value:
        rotDiff = last_rotary_value - current_rotary_value
        if rotDiff > 0:
          print("turned CW")
        else:
          print("turned CCW")
        last_rotary_value = current_rotary_value
      asyncio.sleep(0.01)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program terminated")
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

async def button_detection():
  print("button_detection started")
  try:
    while True:
      if button.is_pressed:
        print("Button pressed")
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program terminated")
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(
    rotary_detection(),
    button_detection()
  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

No matter what order in the `asyncio.gather()` list, only the first one ever gets started.

How do I implement my use case using gpiozero and asyncio in a way that they play nicely with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your async methods ever calls `await`, which means they never yield control back to the scheduler so that another async task can run. You have effectively two synchronous (that is, non-async) methods.

Your `rotary_detection` method would be correct if you remembered to `await` on `asyncio.sleep`:

```py
async def rotary_detection():
  print("rotary_detection started")
  last_rotary_value = 0
  try:
    while True:
      ...

      # Don't forget to await on async tasks
      await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program terminated")
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

However, you will need to introduce an `await` into your `button_pressed` method. Possibly just adding another call to `asyncio.sleep` would make things work, but you may want to consider other options:

1. There are asyncio-supporting libaries for PGIO access, such as [asyncpio](https://github.com/spthm/asyncpio).
2. Ditch asyncio for a threaded model, and use the `gpiozero` `when_held` and `when_pressed` methods to implement your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the nod into the right direction (and correcting the obvious, i.e. the missing `await`). I've now tried introducing the `await`als in the `button_pressed` method like this: ```while True:
      if button.is_pressed:
        print("Button pressed")
      await asyncio.sleep(0.5)```But now the method doesn't register all presses. Might that be a timing (as in wait time) problem ?

Comment: Might be. I would suggest investigating the callback methods that the `gpiozero` library provides; you'll probably find that more effective.

Comment: I guess I'll try out your suggestion. I was really hoping that asyncio would cover my needs...